# Modifying a dataFrame in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sklearn-pandas

i want to delete what after the : in this data (the password) and let just the emails

[emails] https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX9RB.png

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? I mean, we like to fix errors and logic **in code**. While here it seems that you ask to fully program a solution for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be looking at apply.

I think a solution like this:

```
def remove_pw(x): #define your custom function
    y = x.split(":") #simple way to split on the colon
    return y[0] #return only the first part which is the email

df = yourdata

new_df = df['email'].apply(remove_pw)
```

According to your image: ( I am assuming that what is shown is named df and is a valid pandas dataframe.)

```
new_df = df['kobastal@yahoo.com:raskolnik'].apply(remove_pw)
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i want it for all the row

Comment: I just double checked...and it works......you realise that your data needs to be in 1) a pandas dataframe. 2) have a column named 'email' or whatever the column name you set is.

Comment: ok i understand now